# Mapping array in React gives .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having troubles trying to output my errors in react. the data is coming from an external API, and is formatted like so;

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ],
        "address": [
            "The address field is required."
        ],
        "postcode": [
            "The postcode field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

My page which returns the API data and the error component looks something like this;

```
const ShowData = () => {
    const [errorData, setErrorData] = useState([]);

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async ({ name, address, postcode }) => {
        if (errorData) setErrorData([]);

        try {
            // Call API and process here
        } catch (error) {
            setErrorData(error.data);
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {errorData && !Object.keys(errorData).length == 0 &&
                <ErrorComponent errorData={errorData} />
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShowData;


class ErrorComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const errorData = this.props.errorData;

        return (
            <div>{errorData.message}</div>
            <ul>
                {errorData.errors.map(error => {
                    <li>{error}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default ErrorComponent;
```

The error i am receiving is;

```
errorData.errors.map is not a function
```

The following is what i am trying to achieve;

```
<div>The given data was invalid.</div>
<ul>
    <li>The name field is required.</li>
    <li>The address field is required.</li>
    <li>The postcode field is required.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `errorData.errors` is an object, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems.

1. You are trying to map through an object. You should instated do:

```
   <ul>
         {Object.values(errorData.errors).map((e, i) =>
               <li key={i}>{e[0]}</li>
         )}
   </ul>
```

2. Your `map` function is missing the `return` statement, which you can include implicitly by dropping those curly braces as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run .map() on an object. .map() is only usable on iterables.

You might try creating an array from the object using Object.keys, Object.values, Object.entries, or another method that creates an array from an object.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot use `map` on objects, because `map` itself is a method of `Array`. As you can see in the doc, it is [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). So here you could transform the errors to array before mapping. Here I use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) because I also want to display the field that caused error.

There are others problems rather than just iterating the errorData:

- you returned 2 adjacent elements, `div` and `ul`. you must wrap it into one element only. You could use `div` to wrap, but I prefer using `React.Fragment`
- on mapping, you don't return anything to render, so in your example, it will return a list of `undefined`, which would display nothing. Solution here is to use explicit `return`, or shorthand with `() => (<yourelement />)`

```
class ErrorComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const errorData = this.props.errorData;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>{errorData.message}</div>
        <ul>
          {Object.entries(errorData.errors).map(
            ([errorField, errorMessages]) => (
              <li>
                {errorField}: {errorMessages[0]}
              </li>
            )
          )}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

**Live demo**:

[image: Edit dry-haze-mxsg3]